# Need help converting AJAX method of passing variables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, variables

I am decent with PHP but brand new to AJAX. I am currently using AJAX to pull data dynamically from CMS and display within a div on the same page. Currently I am doing this with a selection / option using a form. I am wondering if there is a way i can do this with an A Href and how that might look. I don't want it to refresh the page but work like an A Href would do pass variable values.

Here is what I have.

```
<script>
function showOrder(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getorder.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

<form>
<select name="orders" onchange="showOrder(this.value)">
<option value="">Select an order:</option>
<? foreach($orders as $order){ ?>
  <option value="<? order::num(); ?>"><? order::customer(); ?></option>
  <? } ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want to create an anchor to trigger the function?

Comment: Pretty much the same. You'd get the "text" between `<a id="testATag" href="javascript:void(0)">....</a>` as: `str = document.getElementById("testATag").innerHTML` which could be sent as a query string to `xmlhttp.open("GET","getorder.php?q="+str,true);`. The `href` attribute's value `javascript:void(0)` is to prevent the page from getting redirected to another location, such that the effect of click event on `<a>` is processed.

Comment: I am pretty sure I follow what you are suggesting here, where would I put the <? order::num(); ?>  which points to the record i want to load?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a way to do it what I wanted, it ultimately led to scrapping the A HREF method and going with a button instead.

Here is how I had to structure the button

```
<button onclick="showOrder(this.value)" value="<? echo order::num(); ?>"><? echo order::customer(); ?></button>
```